# Find $ 1 - a^x$, where $x$ is a random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'm trying to find the value of

$$
1 - \left(\frac{99}{100}\right)^N,
$$
where N is a random variable given by

$$
P(N = i) = \frac{e^{-(i-\lambda)^2 / 2\lambda}}{\sqrt{2\pi\lambda}},
$$
with $0\leq i<\infty$.

I'm not sure how to do this - as some background we have a series of trials with success probability $\frac{1}{100}$ each time, with the trials occurring at times given by a poisson distribution with mean $\lambda$. I'm trying to work out the probability that at least one trial is a success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems from your question that $N$ can only take non-negative integer values.  So the Normal approximation to the Poisson distribution will not help, as it is poor in the tails and anyway complicates the calculations.  Here are two equivalent approaches:

1. If the probability of success in each trial is $\frac{1}{100}$ then the distribution of successes is a Poisson distribution with mean $\frac{\lambda}{100}$.  So if $S$ is the number of successes then $$P(S=0) = \exp\left(-\frac{\lambda}{100}\right).$$
2. You could regards the trials as a Poisson *process* with rate $\lambda$ per unit time in which case the successes are a Poisson process with rate $\frac{\lambda}{100}$.  The time until the first success then has an exponential distribution with cumulative distribution function $1- \exp\left(-\frac{\lambda}{100}t\right)$ in which case the probability that there are no successes in one unit of time is $$P(S_1 =0)= \exp\left(-\frac{\lambda}{100}\right).$$